# How can I write a formula to return a certain number if a result falls within a certain range of numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to create a performance report card for my team, but I can't for the life of me write a formula that will return the number rating based on the range the employees result falls in.  So, 0-1.49 should equal 1.00, 1.50-2.49 = 2.00, 2.50-3.49 = 3.00, 3.50-4.49 = 4.00, and 4.50 or higher = 5.00.

```
=IFS(AND(E38>.0149,E38<.0250),2,IF(AND(E38>.0350,E38<.0249),3,IF(AND(E38>.0349,E38<.0450),4,IF(E38>.0449,5,1))))
```

I keep getting an error stating "there are too few arguments for this function".   I am not sure where to go from here.  Please Help!

Comment: The error is because of you are using `IFS()` function and `IF()` as well both and hence why the arguments are not matching the required syntax.  So that said the formula should be `=IF(AND(E38>.0149,E38<.0250),2,IF(AND(E38>.0350,E38<.0249),3,IF(AND(E38>.0349,E38<.0450),4,IF(E38>.0449,5,1))))`

Comment: Also instead of using nested `IF()`s I would suggest you to use a table of reference and then use either `LOOKUP()` or `VLOOKUP()` with approximate match or `XLOOKUP()` function with an approximate match. It will be faster and dynamic as well, as you are not hardcoding within the formulas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sharing in answers only for the reason to show that we can avoid using Nested `IF()`s function and rather use lookup functions with approximate match, which work better and faster, will be dynamic as well.

[image]

---

• Using `LOOKUP()` Function --> Applicable from Excel 2007+ onwards.

Formula used in cell `F38`

```
=IF(E38="","",LOOKUP(E38,$C$32:$E$36))
```

---

• Using `VLOOKUP()` Function --> Applicable from Excel 2007+ onwards.

Formula used in cell `G38`

```
=IF(E38="","",VLOOKUP(E38,$C$32:$E$36,3))
```

---

• Using `XLOOKUP()` Function --> Applicable from Excel 2021+ onwards.

Formula used in cell `H38`

```
=IF(E38:E42="","",XLOOKUP(E38:E42,C32:C36,E32:E36,"",-1))
```

---

• Using Nested `IF()` Function --> Applicable from Excel 2007+ onwards.

Formula used in cell `I38`

```
=IF(E38="","",IF(E38<=1.49,1,IF(E38<=2.49,2,IF(E38<=3.49,3,IF(E38<=4.49,4,5)))))
```

---

• Using Nested `IFS()` Function --> Applicable from Excel 2019+ onwards.

Formula used in cell `J38`

```
=IFS(E38="","",E38<=1.49,1,E38<=2.49,2,E38<=3.49,3,E38<=4.49,4,E38>4.49,5)
```

---

• Using Nested `SWITCH()` Function --> Applicable from Excel 2019+ onwards.

Formula used in cell `K38`

```
=SWITCH(TRUE,E38="","",E38<=1.49,1,E38<=2.49,2,E38<=3.49,3,E38<=4.49,4,5)
```

---